# Filter query with multi-valuable field

Tags: ms-access, filter, vba, multivalue

I have a form name `frm_Report_Filter` for the user to enter the filter criteria. Then, I have a query named `qry_NCR_Report_Finder` to pull out data from a table: `tbl_NCR`, based on the criteria on `frm_Report_Filter`. 
[image: frm_Report_Filter]

The problem started when I tried to enter the criteria for the multi-valuable field: Employee (named `defect_operator` in the table, same thing). I have no idea on how to filter a multi-valuable field.

Here is an example of filtering another NON-Multi-valuable field:
[image]

Here is the Multi-valuable field (and obviously this is not working):

[image: Multi-valuable field]

So the goal is just when the user chooses ONE employee on `frm_Report_Filter` the query will display the record that contains that name. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Best advice is to redesign your tables to not have such fields. As "smart" as they may seem, they will cause you nothing but trouble in the long run.

Comment: PMJI: I removed the tag "multivalue-database" since this does not pertain to non-RDBMS databases which are designed to accommodate the specific case defined here. I recommend editing to change all references from "multi-valuable" to "multivalue" - the tag there is correct but there is no such thing as "multi-valuable". Good luck.